# Ubuntu 22.04 POE+ hat fan control - seeking updated guidance

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, poe

I recently updated to 64-bit 22.04 Server on a Headless Raspberry Pi 4B 8Gb model with a POE+ hat, and the fan speed control on the POE+ hat seems to have changed. Searching Google/forums only shows up the advice that worked on 20 and maybe 21 (I skipped 21), but is not working on 22.

I noted that my fan speed control overlays were no longer in `/boot/firmware/config.txt` after the upgrade, so I added it back - though it seems to be ignored. My `/boot/firmware/config.txt` has this:

```
# config for POE+ hat fan control
dtoverlay=rpi-poe-plus
```

After boot, I check the type with the following command:

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/type
```

and it returns `pwm-fan`, not the expected `rpi-poe-plus`.

I see posts regarding moving the configuration to `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-rpi-fan.rules`, and in experimentation have observed that this does seem to set the fan speed, but ... They don't seem to have the weight of authoritative knowledge - why is this working?

I'm imagining that somebody at Ubuntu/Raspberry Pi has been trying to make the end-user experience better so fans just work, but I don't think I'm looking in the right place to find documentation for that change.

My questions for 22.04:

- Is there actual documentation of how to do this somewhere?
- Do I still need to add the overlay in /boot/firmware/config.txt?
- Do I still need to differentiate rpi-poe from rpi-poe-plus?
- Is there a supported usercfg.txt anymore (if so, what is the correct name of this file)?
- Am I missing something else?

Comment: "somebody at Ubuntu/Raspberry Pi" won't be doing ANYTHING because there is no such entity. Ubuntu do their own thing. Raspberry Pi Ltd. do not produce Ubuntu software.

Comment: @Milliways Consider it shorthand for the people who make changes to that software.

Comment: *"shorthand for the people who make changes to that software"* -> Unfortunately, it seems those people do not have time to frequent here; the ten most recent questions tagged `ubuntu` (which go back ~ 1 month) either have no answer, or just one answer from someone who explicitly or implicitly isn't actually a user of Ubuntu on the Pi.